# Hover on a video or div, show the div on the video

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div, and it randoms the content from database. The content can be text or video and keep in a div.

And I want to show the `Read more` text, whenever the user hover on the text or a video as example of Video Manager below:

[image]

Any suggestion please.

Comment: I don't see "read more" text in the image.  Are these flash videos or html5 ones?

Comment: C'mon seriously?  I am not in any way criticizing your english, but I am criticizing your explanation of your problem.  No idea what you're actually asking, and your screenshot in no way correlates to what your asking, especially in regards to a "read more"...

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Sorry if inconvenient, because my English is poor. What I want is to show read more text(the example above just the demo). I want to show label read more text as the Watch, Edit and Delete button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many tutorials for that you can start searching them, maybe this tutorial might help watch out demos http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/#demo1

HTML

```
<img id="d1" src="photos/1.jpg" width="300" height="240" />
<div class="contenthover">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum pulvinar ante quis augue lobortis volutpat. </p>
    <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.contenthover { padding:20px 20px 10px 20px; }
.contenthover, .contenthover h3, contenthover a { color:#fff; }
.contenthover h3, .contenthover p { margin:0 0 10px 0; line-height:1.4em; padding:0; }
.contenthover a.mybutton { display:block; float:left; padding:5px 10px; background:#3c9632; color:#fff; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }
.contenthover a.mybutton:hover { background:#34742d }
```

Jquery script:

```
$('#d1').contenthover({
    overlay_background:'#000',
    overlay_opacity:0.8
});
```

Comment: It works well on a div with text but didn't work with div contain video.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create another div and set its position absolutely,then you can do the things what you wanted to do.Don't know that if I'm right.